# Possible side effect of Stream.peek changing state and why not use it like this

Tags: java, java-stream

A solution that I came up on another Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355185/java-8-stream-api-filter-out-empty-value-from-map) that is using Stream.peek operation works but still seems like is not right because it mutates state in the `Stream.peek` method.

While researching ([here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308977/is-it-an-antipattern-to-use-peek-to-modify-a-stream-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717/in-java-streams-is-peek-really-only-for-debugging)) on `Stream.peek` usage whether it is ok to mutate state I am still not fully convinced that `Stream.peek` should not mutate state (including state of collection that is source of the `Stream`).

Here is what [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) says:

> **This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline:**

And then:

> Parameters: action - a **non-interfering** action to perform on the 
>   elements as they are consumed from the stream.
>
> For well-behaved non-interfering
>   stream sources, the source can be modified before the terminal
>   operation commences and those modifications will be reflected in the
>   covered elements.All the streams returned from JDK collections, and
>   most other JDK classes, are well-behaved in this manner.

Seems like **non-interfering** action does includes changing the state of collection in the stream.

Here is the code that uses `Stream.peek`.

```
Map< String, List<Test> > userTests = new HashMap<>();

Map< String, List<Test> > filtered  = userTests.entrySet().stream()
        .peek( e -> e.setValue( modifyListAndReturnIt( e.getValue() ) ) )
        .filter( e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty() ) //check if modified list in peek has been emptied
        .collect( Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue() ) );

    public static List<Test> modifyListAndReturnIt(List<Test> list){
        if (somecondition) list.clear();
        return list;
    }
```

1) Can the above code have any side effect?

2) Why not use peek in such a way. The Javadoc does not seem to not allow it?

Comment: can you show the definition of the Streams source for completeness and the definition of the method being used within the Stream pipeline?. Also, as for your second question you’ll only need to ask your self _”why would the java doc state that the method is for debugging purposes only”_? Then ask your self if the implementation of the “peek” method changes, what will happen to my code?

Comment: My advice is that, you should always use a method the way it was intended to be used. Nothing more.

Comment: @Aominè. Actually the Javadoc does not state that is should "only" be used for debugging, It says "mostly" which is not same as "only".

Comment: You may want to read the rest of the java.util.stream documentation to which you’ve linked, particularly the [side effects section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).  For instance, there are no guarantees “that different operations on the "same" element within the same stream pipeline are executed in the same thread.”  So even if your code happens to work today, it may not work in a future Java release, or on a machine with different concurrency capabilities (like more CPU cores).

Comment: @VGR. The doc does not really say what they consider a side effect and where it applies. But it does mention this: ***A small number of stream operations, such as forEach() and peek(), can operate only via side-effects; these should be used with care.***

Comment: In the absence of an explicit definition, I think you can assume any mutation operation is a side effect.  Even if it’s thread-safe, you have no guarantee of its order of execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you seem to do *looks harmless* as Brian Goetz states in [comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557251/java-lambda-expression-mapping-and-then-modifying-a-list/33557322#comment54894478_33557322).

Now the problem with peek is that if you do side effects inside it - you would expect these side effects to *actually happen*. So, suppose you would want to alter some property of some object like this:

```
myUserList.stream()
          .peek(u -> u.upperCaseName())
          .count()
```

In java-8 your `peek` would be indeed called, in 9 - it is not - there is no need to call `peek` here since the size can be computed without it anyway.

While being on the same path, imagine that your terminal operation is a short-circuit one, like `findFirst` or `findAny` - you are *not* going to process all elements *of the source* - you might get just a few of them through the pipeline.

Things might get even stranger if your `peek` would rely on a encounter order even if your terminal operation would not be a short-circuit one. The intermediate operations for parallel processing do not have an encounter order, while the terminal ones - do. Imagine the surprises you might be facing.

Comment: now that I've written this and actually saw that you linked your question to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717/in-java-streams-is-peek-really-only-for-debugging; it looks like and exact duplicate to me - even my answer looks like a summarization of that :| I will close it as a duplicate if there are more votes towards that

Comment: Unfortunately there does not seem a clear answer to this. Some say dont use `peek` since it is not intended for this type of usage but some say it can be used but with great care. Seems like no general thumb of the rule can be defined about `peek` or even any other intermediate operation like `map` that can potentially change state too.

Comment: @tsolakp you're right in some way - I agree. In these cases I stick to the official documentation and what it says and it clearly states that side-effects are bad. Of course people might try to abuse this in some ways, it's entirely up to you if you want to be on that side

Comment: @tsolakp the same thing is true for example when a `reduce` violates the `identity` for example - compiler can't "force" you to do the right thing...