# How to remove multiple elements from Set/Map AND knowing which ones were removed?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a method that has to remove any element listed in a (small) `Set<K> keysToRemove` from some (potentially large) `Map<K,V> from`. But `removeAll()` doesn't do, as I need to return all keys that were actually removed, since the map might or might not contain keys that require removal.

Old-school code is straight forward:

```
public Set<K> removeEntries(Map<K, V> from) {
    Set<K> fromKeys = from.keySet();
    Set<K> removedKeys = new HashSet<>();
    for (K keyToRemove : keysToRemove) {
        if (fromKeys.contains(keyToRemove)) {
            fromKeys.remove(keyToRemove);
            removedKeys.add(keyToRemove);
        }
    }
    return removedKeys;
}
```

The same, written using streams:

```
Set<K> fromKeys = from.keySet();
return keysToRemove.stream()
        .filter(fromKeys::contains)
        .map(k -> {
            fromKeys.remove(k);
            return k;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I find that a bit more concise, but I also find that lambda too clunky.

Any suggestions how to achieve the same result in less clumsy ways?

Comment: How about just collecting all keys that can be removed and then call `removeAll()` on that filtered set? Or how about "filtering" on `fromKeys::remove`?

Comment: I believe and inferring from the answers here, the improvement that comes mostly out of any change is by using `if (fromKeys.remove(keyToRemove)) {
                removedKeys.add(keyToRemove);
            }` instead of using both contains and remove in `if (fromKeys.contains(keyToRemove)) {
            fromKeys.remove(keyToRemove);
            removedKeys.add(keyToRemove);
        }`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The “old-school code” should rather be

```
public Set<K> removeEntries(Map<K, ?> from) {
    Set<K> fromKeys = from.keySet(), removedKeys = new HashSet<>(keysToRemove);
    removedKeys.retainAll(fromKeys);
    fromKeys.removeAll(removedKeys);
    return removedKeys;
}
```

Since you said that `keysToRemove` is rather small, the copying overhead likely doesn’t matter. Otherwise, use the loop, but don’t do the hash lookup twice:

```
public Set<K> removeEntries(Map<K, ?> from) {
    Set<K> fromKeys = from.keySet();
    Set<K> removedKeys = new HashSet<>();
    for(K keyToRemove : keysToRemove)
        if(fromKeys.remove(keyToRemove)) removedKeys.add(keyToRemove);
    return removedKeys;
}
```

You can express the same logic as a stream as

```
public Set<K> removeEntries(Map<K, ?> from) {
    return keysToRemove.stream()
        .filter(from.keySet()::remove)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

but since this is a stateful filter, it is highly discouraged. A cleaner variant would be

```
public Set<K> removeEntries(Map<K, ?> from) {
    Set<K> result = keysToRemove.stream()
        .filter(from.keySet()::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    from.keySet().removeAll(result);
    return result;
}
```

and if you want to maximize the “streamy” usage, you can replace `from.keySet().removeAll(result);` with `from.keySet().removeIf(result::contains)`, which is quiet expensive, as it is iterating over the larger map, or with `result.forEach(from.keySet()::remove)`, which doesn’t have that disadvantage, but still, isn’t more readable than `removeAll`.

All in all, the “old-school code” is much better than that.

Comment: Was working around with the existing code. Wouldn't `public Set<K> removeEntries(Map<K, ?> from) {
        Set<K> removedKeys = new HashSet<>();
        for (K keyToRemove : keysToRemove) {
            if (from.keySet().remove(keyToRemove)) {
                removedKeys.add(keyToRemove);
            }
        }
        return removedKeys;
    }` be a better old school code than the `retainAll`, `removeAll` solution. I meant to be focussing(nitpicking) on the single iteration versus two iterations with their implementation. (I might just be wrong though in inferring so.)

Comment: @Naman that’s what I posted as second variant, right for the case that the iteration matters. However, the `retainAll`/`removeAll` combo will iterate over the set that has been specified by the OP as being rather small.

Comment: Oh, yes the second variant indeed is the same. But wouldn't the `removeAll` iterate the `fromKeys` instead of `keysToRemove` there? About the first stream variant, how about using the predicate for reduction using `partitioningBy`, wrote a [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56585387/1746118)?

Comment: @Naman that’s hitting implementation details, but I assume that it works like [`AbstractSet.removeAll(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractSet.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)), if not even inheriting right that method: “*This implementation determines which is the smaller of this set and the specified collection, by invoking the size method on each. …[etc]*”. Using a stateful predicate for `partitioningBy` is as discouraged as for `filter`, but with the latter, you’re collection another set of actually unwanted elements…

Comment: Slightly off topic, but how would do you verify the correctness of your solution? Do you actually write everything from scratch in IntelliJ (`public static void main` and all) and verify? Asking because I'm not familiar with streams or the java tag.

Comment: @cs95 well yes, for most SO answers, I write some test code, either from scratch or using the question’s code as starting point, if any. Depending on the context, it might be in Netbeans, Eclipse or command line. When it comes to compiler-dependent behavior, I also have batch files to compile&run the same source code with different JDKs.

Comment: @Naman my last sentence was written in a hurry. I wanted to say, that `partitioningBy` does more work when necessary, when only one of the two sets is needed. Besides that, it’s like the `filter` approach.

Comment: @Holger I got what you meant by another set anyway. Thanks 

Comment: When you're already creating an [mcve] for your tests, why not post it so that others can check it out more quickly? At least, I *usually* try to do this, along with some "dummy/test" data and syso's that show the results...

Comment: @Marco13 I often do this, especially for questions containing an example, but not every answer would benefit from examples. Further, not all of my test code is a minimal example. And sometimes, it gets edited for other tests, without having all test in the code at a time, so it would require significant cleanup before getting published.

Answer (score 13):

More concise solution, but still with unwanted **side effect** in the `filter` call:

```
Set<K> removedKeys =
    keysToRemove.stream()
                .filter(fromKeys::remove)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

[`Set.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) already returns `true` if the `set` contained the specified element.

P.S. In the end, I would probably stick with the "old-school code".

Comment: Exactly my thought ;) - It just feels a little hacky because we're "filtering" on a method that actually represents a side effect.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn’t use Streams for this.  I would take advantage of [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
public Set<K> removeEntries(Map<K, V> from) {
    Set<K> matchingKeys = new HashSet<>(from.keySet());
    matchingKeys.retainAll(keysToRemove);

    from.keySet().removeAll(matchingKeys);

    return matchingKeys;
}
```

Comment: That’s pointing into the right direction, but you are copying the “potentially large” `from` map’s keyset whereas you can copy the “small” `keysToRemove` instead, as the intersection of a and b is the same as of b and a. Further, `matchingKeys` is potentially smaller than `keysToRemove`, so `removeAll(matchingKeys)` is preferable.

Comment: @Holger I see your point, but the Set is merely copying references, which seems benign to me, unless the Map’s size is truly huge.  You’re right about removeAll(matchingKeys) though.  Updated.

Comment: It’s not just copying references, but hashing. And since the OP stated the expected sizes and swapping the two is trivial, I’d do this. In fact, [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584064/2711488).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the stream and the removeAll

```
Set<K> fromKeys = from.keySet();
Set<K> removedKeys = keysToRemove.stream()
    .filter(fromKeys::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
fromKeys.removeAll(removedKeys);
return removedKeys;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
Set<K> removedKeys = keysToRemove.stream()
        .filter(from::containsKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
removedKeys.forEach(from::remove);
```

It's similar to *Oleksandr*'s answer, but avoiding the side effect. But I would stick with that answer, if you are looking for performance.

Alternatively you could use [`Stream.peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) for the remove, but be careful with other side effects (see the comments). So I would not recommend that.

```
Set<K> removedKeys = keysToRemove.stream()
        .filter(from::containsKey)
        .peek(from::remove)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Never use peek for anything other than debugging! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356992/possible-side-effect-of-stream-peek-changing-state-and-why-not-use-it-like-this and the questions linked in it

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath Makes perfect sense. Fun fact: I tried my initial lambda again, with map. IntelliJ suggests to replace that call to map() to peek() ;-)

Comment: Or more general general: [In Java streams is peek really only for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/2711488)

Answer (score 3):

To add another variant to the approaches, one could also partition the keys and return the required `Set` as:

```
public Set<K> removeEntries(Map<K, ?> from) {
    Map<Boolean, Set<K>> partitioned = keysToRemove.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(k -> from.keySet().remove(k),
                    Collectors.toSet()));
    return partitioned.get(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Also leaves a choice of using the keys that were not a part of the keySet of the map. (just in case)